# Docker does not copy json file inside image

Tags: docker, docker-image

Hello i do not understand why i can't put a `json` file inside a docker image.

I have `3` elements that i want to be copied to the image:
-`publish` (publish folder)
- `dockerfile`
-`conf.json`  //configuartion json

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","publish/Server.dll"]
```

When i look inside the container with `-it` the `folder` is copied ,same as the `dockerfile` but not the `json`.Instead there is a `txt` file `temp.txt` that says:

```
You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

What can i do to put the `json` file inside the image too?

Comment: Check for `.dockerignore` file and ensure that it is not excluding json files

Comment: I have no `dockerignore` file !

Comment: what local directory are you in when you run `docker build`?